# SwiftUI: Clickable links or buttons in alert

Tags: swiftui

I have made an alert into my app that pops up when user opens the app for the first time and I would like it to have the accept button and 2 more buttons that are a link to my privacy policy and terms and conditions. Here is the alerts code that I currently have.

```
.alert(isPresented: $alertShouldBeShown, content: {
                
    Alert(title: Text("Thank you for downloading this app"),
    message: Text("By tapping the button, you agree to accept the terms and conditions and the privacy policy"),
    primaryButton: Alert.Button.default(
    Text("Continue & Accept"), action: {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "FirstStart")
    })
)
})
```

I have only been able to make another button using the `secondaryButton:` but I would like to have 3 buttons in total. How would it be possible? Thank you.

Is it even possible since SwiftUI gives two buttons so I just should make a new view that has all the necessary links and buttons and when pressed accept it goes into the main view?

Comment: You forgot to show how you attempted to add these buttons.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a [Link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/link) in the body of your alert.

Comment: On iOS 16, putting a Link inside an Alert message will render plain text without a blue link. Also, if you use SwiftUI’s support for Markdown to create links using a Text field, it also will not work, only rendering plain text instead of blue links.